# getting pointers to vector elements

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I run into an issue which I don't quite understand:

I am creating an object Edge with

```
edge_vec1.push_back(Edge(src,dest));
```

Then I want to keep a pointer to this Edge in a separate vector:

```
edge_vec2.push_back(&edge_vec1.back());
```

However, once I add the second Edge object, the pointer to the first Edge in edge_vec2 is invalidated(gets some random data). Is it because the pointer in edge_vec2 actually points to some place in edge_vec1, and not the underlying element? I can avoid this by creating my Edge objects on the heap, but I'd like to understand what's going on.

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want to store a pointer to an array element in the first place? Can't you just store an index?

Comment: @InternetAussie Well, I do store the element in the first vector. But assume the first container is actually something more complicated, e.g. adjacency list. Then there is no index, but I want to keep an option to quickly iterate over all the edges

Comment: The simplest solution is to store pointers in both containers and create objects dynamically.

Comment: This question and the answers are very container-dependent. Invalidation happens very differently for different containers; for example, it’s harder to invalidate the iterators in a `std::list`. If the first container isn’t literally a `vector`, then this is not a detail you can simplify away for this question.

Comment: @Logman yup right up until you count in having to manage all that dynamically allocated memory. Smart pointers will help on that front quite a bit.

Comment: The reason for requiring std::vector to store its content in a single block of memory is actually to make it incredibly fast to iterate @LazyCat. Iterating over the complete (or parts of it, or accessing via index) container might be faster than iterating over pointers and dereferencing each individually.

Comment: @user4581301 I will say it depend on speed you want but I will also go into smart pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a new element is added to a vector then the vector can be reallocated. So the previous values of pointers to the elements of the vector can be invalid.

You should at first reserve enough memory for the vector preventing the reallocation.

```
edge_vec2.reserve( SomeMaxValue );
```

Comment: Thanks, I suspected that's what was going on. I guess, if the value available is only as a vector element, it cannot have a permanent pointer to it.

Comment: Not if you might grow the vector, no.

Comment: @DanielH I think that the number of elements that represents Edges is fixed for a given graph.

Answer (score 3):

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back:

> If the new size() is greater than capacity() then all iterators and references (including the past-the-end iterator) are invalidated. Otherwise only the past-the-end iterator is invalidated.

It's a bad idea to depend on pointers/references to objects in a `vector` when you are adding items to it. It is better to store the value of the index and then use the index to fetch the item from the `vector`.

```
edge_vec2.push_back(edge_vec1.size()-1);
```

Later, you can use:

```
edge_vec1[edge_vec2[i]]
```

for some valid value of `i`.

Comment: Indices are not an option for me (see comments), but thanks for confirming, that my pointers get invalidated.

Answer (score 1):

The requirements of std::vector are that the underlying storage is a continuous block of memory. As such, a vector has to reallocate all of its elements when you want to insert an element but the currently allocated block is not large enough to hold the additional element. When this happens, all iterators and pointers are invalidated, as the complete block is reallocated (moved) to a completely different part of memory.

The member function capacity can be used to query the maximum amount of elements which can be inserted without reallocating the underlying memory block. Examplary code querying this:

```
std::vector<int> vec;
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
     bool still_has_space = vec.capacity() > vec.size();
     if (!still_has_space) std::cout << "Reallocating block\n"; 
     vec.push_back(i);
}
```

In case the strong guarantee of contiguous memory layout is not need, you might be better of using std::deque instead of std::vector. It allows pushing elements on either end without moving around any other element. You trade this for slightly worse iteration speeds.

```
 std::deque<int> deq;
 std::vector<int*> pointers;
 for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
      deq.push_back(i);
      pointers.push_back(&deq.back());
 }
 for(auto p : pointers) std::cout << *p << "\n"; // Valid
```